# How can I rephrase my sentence and make it a bit shorter?

Tags: sentence

Do you have any suggestion on how to I shrink this sentence and write it more concisely?

> For instance, each year, during Christmas and new year's holidays, our company integrates its default salary scheme with a bonus salary scheme (called FunPlus) to further stimulate its employees to work harder.

Comment: "Our company pays its staff a 'FunPlus' bonus at Christmas and New Year as a reward for working hard." Note that I switched it from an *incentive* to a *reward* to make them feel more valued, rather than goaded like farm animals.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you really so much for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting off a sentence with an action-packed verb furnishes it with an extra zing. I therefore suggest recasting the sentence as:

> To incentivize its employees, our company pays them a 'FunPlus' bonus at Christmas and New Year.

Indeed, you could foreground *our company* in the above example by making it the *Subject* of the sentence, but the nuance in meaning would be a bit different then.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable point

Comment: The edit has completely changed it from the version that was "accepted."

Comment: @Weather Vane: I guess I was a bit hasty in reading the question. I overlooked the _brevity_ part the question is really asking about and focussed more on the grammar of it. I later set it right.

Comment: Could you please kindly bring back the previous version?

Comment: @Reza2020: _To further stimulate its employees to work harder, our company merges its default salary scheme with a bonus salary scheme (FunPlus) at Christmas and New Year._ But it's about as lengthy as the original sentence,questio and doesn't meet the demand of the question.

Comment: @user405662 Thank you so much ^_^